# Joint distribution of the signs of the partial sums of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Consider some i.i.d. standard normal random variables. What is the joint distribution of the signs of their partial sums?

More formally, define a sequence of random variables $(S_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ by $S_1=X_1$ and $S_k=S_{k-1}+X_k$ for every $k\geqslant2$, where $(X_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. standard normal. 
One asks to compute $$p(\varepsilon)=P(A^\varepsilon),$$ for every $n$ and every (deterministic) $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ in $\{-,+\}^n$, where $A^\varepsilon$ is the event $$A^\varepsilon=\bigcap_{k=1}^n[\varepsilon_kS_k\geqslant0].$$
Some known facts (the four first items being obvious):

- For $n=1$, $p(+)=p(-)=\frac12$.
- For every $n$, the sum of $p(\varepsilon)$ over every $\varepsilon$ in $\{-,+\}^n$ is $1$.
- For every $\varepsilon$, $p(\varepsilon)=p(-\varepsilon)$.
- For every $\varepsilon$, $p(\varepsilon)=p(\varepsilon,+)+p(\varepsilon,-)$.
- For $n=2$, $p(+,+)=p(-,-)=\frac38$ and $p(+,-)=p(-,+)=\frac18$.
- For every $\eta$ in $\{-,+\}$ and $\varepsilon$ in $\{-,+\}^n$, $p(\varepsilon,\eta,-\eta)\lt\tfrac12p(\varepsilon,\eta)\lt p(\varepsilon,\eta,\eta).$
- For each given $n$, $p(\ )$ is maximal on $\{-,+\}^n$ at the two constant sequences $\varepsilon=(+,+,\ldots,+)$ and $\varepsilon=(-,-,\ldots,-)$.

**Note:** This reformulates and generalizes [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1178124), which probably meant to ask for $p(+,+,+).$ The facts recalled above yield $\tfrac3{16}\lt p(+,+,+)\lt\tfrac38.$

> *Sub-question:* Compute $p(+,+,+).$

Comment: It seems that piling change of variable upon change of variable and using some unnamable ingredients, one can get $$p(+,+,+)=\frac5{16}.$$

Comment: That, or being able to visualize portions of the unit sphere better than I.

Comment: For the record, **4** users saw fit (for purely mathematical reasons, no doubt) to downvote this question. This site is wonderful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire "normal distributions" aspect of this problem is a red herring.  If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. normally distributed random variables with mean $0$, then the joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a multivariate normal distribution centered at the origin, which has complete spherical symmetry.

Now, each sequence $(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)$ of signs determines a convex cone $C(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$
\epsilon_1 x_1 \geq 0,\quad \epsilon_2(x_1+x_2) \geq 0,\quad\ldots,\quad \epsilon_n(x_1+\cdots + x_n) \geq 0.
$$
Then
$$
p(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n) \;=\; \frac{\mu\bigl(S^{n-1} \cap C(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)\bigr)}{\mu(S^{n-1})}
$$
where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mu$ is the volume measure on $S^{n-1}$.  For example, $p({+}{+}{+}\cdots{+})$ is the probability that the partial sums of the coordinates are all positive for a random point chosen on the unit $(n-1)$-sphere.

For $n=3$, the region on $S^2$ corresponding to $+++$ is a spherical triangle with angles $\dfrac{3\pi}4$, $\cos^{-1}\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$, and  $\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\right)$. (These vertex angles are the same as the angles between the planes, which can be computed via dot products.)  The area of this triangle is the angular excess:
$$
\frac{3\pi}{4} + \cos^{-1}\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) + \cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\right) - \pi \;=\; \frac{5\pi}{4}.
$$
The whole sphere has area $4\pi$, so
$$
p(+++) \;=\; \frac{5\pi/4}{4\pi} \;=\; \frac{5}{16}.
$$
Similar computations show that
$$
p(++-) = \frac{1}{16},\quad
p(+-+) = -\frac{1}{16} + \frac{\tan^{-1}(2\sqrt{2})}{4\pi}\approx 0.0355,$$
and
$$p(+--) = \dfrac{3}{16}-\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(2\sqrt{2})}{4\pi} \approx 0.0895.
$$

For $n=4$, the regions on the sphere $S^3$ are spherical tetrahedra, where the dihedral angles between the faces are the same as the angles between the defining planes.  For example $p({+}{+}{+}{+})$ is the volume of a spherical tetrahedron with the following dihedral angles, divided by the volume of $S^3$:
$$
\theta_{12} = \frac{3\pi}{4},\ \theta_{13} = \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right),\ \theta_{14}= \frac{2\pi}{3},\ \theta_{23}=\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right),\ \theta_{24}=\frac{3\pi}{4},\ \theta_{34}=\frac{5\pi}{6}.
$$
Based on *Mathematica* computations (using the formula in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2584v4.pdf)) it seems that $$p({+}{+}{+}{+}) = \dfrac{35}{128}\qquad\text{and}\qquad p({+}{+}{+}{-})= \dfrac{5}{128},$$ which agrees with d.k.o.'s formula in these cases.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do we agree that the value of $p(+--)$ shows that not every $p(\varepsilon)$ is rational? Would you have an idea for computing $p(++\cdots+)$ in every dimension?

Answer (score 3):

Denote $\mathbf Z_n=(Z_1,Z_2,...,Z_n)'$ then

$$\mathbf S_n=A\mathbf X_n$$

where $A$ is the lower triangular part of $\mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n'$. So, by definition $\mathbf S_n$ is jointly normal with zero mean and covariance matrix $\Sigma=AA'$ s.t. $\Sigma_{i,j}=i\wedge j$. Consequently,

$$\widetilde{\mathbf S}_n\equiv diag[\epsilon]\times\mathbf S_n \sim\mathcal N(0,\widetilde{\Sigma})$$

where $\widetilde{\Sigma}_{i,j}=(i\wedge j)\cdot (\epsilon_i\epsilon_j)$.

Finally, $p(\epsilon)=P\{\widetilde{\mathbf S}_n\ge \mathbf 0\}=P\{\widetilde{\mathbf S}_{n,1}\ge 0,...,\widetilde{\mathbf S}_{n,n}\ge 0\}$.

---

**Edit**: some simulations.

The computation of the multivariate normal integral is pretty difficult as @Did mentioned in the comments. However, simulations reveal an interesting "result"...

Here is the graph of the simulated conditional probability $p_c[n]\equiv\hat{P}\{\widetilde{\mathbf S}_{n,n}\ge \mathbf 0|\widetilde{\mathbf S}_{n-1}\ge \mathbf 0\}$ for $n\le 100$ and $\epsilon=\{+,...,+\}$ (blue circles):

[image]

The fitted curve is $\hat{p}_c[n]\approx 1-\frac{1}{2n}$ So, assuming that this relation holds we can find a formula for $p_u[n]\equiv$$ P\{\widetilde{\mathbf S}_n\ge \mathbf 0\}$ by solving the following recurrence relation

$$p_u[n]=p_u[n-1]\cdot \Big(1-\frac{1}{2n}\Big)\text{, }p_u[1]=\frac{1}{2}$$

which yields

$$p_u[n]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(n+0.5)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$$

Comment: I am following you until $p(\epsilon)=P(\tilde S_n\ge0)$, provided $(\tilde S_n\ge0)=(\forall i,(\tilde S_n)_i\ge0)$. But how does this yield the actual values $p(\epsilon)$, for example $p(+++)$ and $p(++-)$?

Comment: @Did Are you looking for some trick which allows to compute this probability without calculating triple integrals? Actually, I used Maple to compute those integrals :)

Comment: Indeed I am, if by "trick" you mean "principle" or "proof". For example it seems that $2^{n+1}p(\varepsilon)$ is always a positive integer, depending on $\varepsilon$. Is this true? Why is that so? What are these integers? Is $2^{n+1}p(\varepsilon)=2^{n-1}+1$ for every $n$ or is this a coincidence for $n=1,2,3$? And so on.

Comment: @Did Seems to be true for $\epsilon=(++...+)$. Numerical integration (for large $n$-s) gives very close result. However, it will be interesting to see a formal proof...